# Can we add the favicons/colours onto the footer for each of the displayed sites

Tags: discussion, status-declined, user-interface, footer

Okay, so I just noticed the new footer. Nice way to incorporate more sites!

One thing though, it just looks like a wall of text now. Could we possibly have the favicons for each of the site to make it look a little better? I think that makes it more intuitive when you're trying to look for one of them too (if you know the site), it makes them stand out (heuristics and all that :)).

If not favicons, maybe a use of colours? Open to interpretation on that one.

Comment: Not sure about the favicon idea, that could get very messy very quickly. However some sort of indicator / bullet might be a good idea.

Comment: Yes; I want more color

Comment: Maybe something on-hover? Pretty sure the rainbow is something the new footer is trying to avoid

Comment: https://twitter.com/Schabse/status/327082322740539392

Comment: @SLaks Good shout! Get the question tweeted ;)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this idea would improve things.

We basically have two use cases:  Existing users who use the footer to switch between sites, and new users who want to see what else is available.

In the previous case, I think you will quickly learn where your favorite sites are in the list. Icons could help, but it would just make things too messy.  Color just isn't inherently representative of anything, so you would basically have to go through memorizing the color for  your favorite sites. And if you're going to do that, why not just memorize the position and be done with it?

For new users who are just browsing, I don't think icons or colors would be helpful at all.

Comment: I think it would be closer to the truth to say that colours are unsustainable, in fact you've pretty much run out already...